# The Multi-part identifier could not be bound update query

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2008-r2

I’m trying to do an update on a table that’s on a linked server (Server2). I’m running the update from my server (Server1). When I execute the below code

```
IF EXISTS (SELECT ID FROM Server2.database.dbo.table)
UPDATE Server2.database.dbo.table
SET Server2.database.dbo.table.Revoked = a.Revoked
FROM Server1.database.dbo.table a
WHERE Server2.database.dbo.table.ID = a.ID
```

I keep getting the following error message:

> The multi-part identifier “Server2.database.dbo.table.Revoked” could not be bound.

Any ideas on how to fix this?

Comment: Put the Server instance name in square brackets []

Answer (score 1):

SQL is complaining about the number of prefixes, the correct way of writing this should be: `[linkedservername].[databasename].[tableschema].[table]`.

If you add the column name to the syntax above, it will be understood as another prefix. So you can create an alias to the update, and reference the alias instead of the whole reference.

```
IF EXISTS (SELECT ID FROM Server2.database.dbo.table)
BEGIN
    UPDATE MyAlias
    SET MyAlias.Revoked = a.Revoked
    FROM Server2.database.dbo.table MyAlias
        INNER JOIN Server1.database.dbo.table a
            ON MyAlias.ID = a.ID
END
```